# Detect route change in All Angular2 components

Tags: angular, router

i know how to detect route changes in each component, so i have to put the **same code** in each one to get this changes

but my purpose is to detect route changes in general way, is there any possibility to do this ?

Comment: Just detect route changes in root component.

Comment: but in root component detection happened just one time

Comment: Do you subscribe router.events? Could you show us your root component code?

Comment: you are right @KamilMyśliwiec thank's

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your route detection logic in the top component, which has the topmost/first `<router-outlet>`.

In my case this would be AppComponent

.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

.ts

```
export class AppComponent {

   constructor(
       private router: Router
   ) { 
       router.events.subscribe(event => console.log(event));
   }
}
```

Comment: that's work fine, i have just another question is there any possibility to get params from the route ?

Comment: You need to inject `ActivatedRoute` in the component and subscribe to the `params` property in the constructor.

Comment: in the root compoenent ?

Comment: Probably yes, whereever you need access to the `params` property

Comment: this.router.params.subscribe((val) => { console.log("detection : ",val) }); ==> doesn't work using ActivatedRoute

Comment: even the route changes detection doesn't happen using activateRoute :/